# Launching a new activity - android

Tags: android, undefined

i'm new to programming in Java and android... Here is my question, again not sure if the information I provide is sufficient.
What I'm trying to do is create a simple two activity app....
So i have the main activity and a user clicks a button and a new activity is launched that sets a new layout.

I've looked at the two following websites:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html#fragments_tutorial

Both very useful but when I tried to implement had issues.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button buttonLoadProfile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadProfile);
    buttonLoadProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent profileIntent = new Intent();
            profileIntent.setClass(getActivity(),LoadProfile.class);
//              setContentView(R.layout.profile_layout);
        }
    });
}
```

The error I get is "The method getActivity() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}"

Comment: asked follow up question to clear some things up

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13004361/intent-setclassgetactivity-class-vs-intentthis-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
    Intent profileIntent = new Intent( MainActivity.this, LoadProfile.class );
    startActivity(profileIntent);
```

This will resolve the enclosing class from the inner.

Comment: follow up question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13004361/intent-setclassgetactivity-class-vs-intentthis-class

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call `getActivity()` in the new `View.OnClickListener()` interface because it does not have the method described in it. 
Instead do the following:

```
Intent profileIntent = new Intent(this, LoadProfile.class);
```

And add:

```
startActivity(profileIntent);
```

To summarize the change:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent profileIntent = new Intent(this, LoadProfile.class);
            startActivity(profileIntent);

        }
```

Comment: hm... it now says that the constructor for Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){},Class<LoadProfile>) is undefined, should use MainActivity.this no idea why but it worked that way

Comment: follow up question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13004361/intent-setclassgetactivity-class-vs-intentthis-class