# intent.setClass(getActivity, .class) vs Intent(this, .class)

Tags: android, android-intent

I had this problem

[Launching a new activity - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003898/launching-a-new-activity-android)

and don't understand why the original code was wrong. Also, even more confusing later on in the activity i have the following code which works using getActivity() what is the difference why does it work in one case and not the other?

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        EditText dobText = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        String dobStr = dobText.getText().toString();
        int day = Integer.valueOf(dobStr.replaceAll("([0-9]*)/[0-9]+/[0-9]+","$1"));
        int month = Integer.valueOf(dobStr.replaceAll("[0-9]+/([0-9]+)/[0-9]+", "$1"))-1;
        int year = Integer.valueOf(dobStr.replaceAll("[0-9]+/[0-9]+/([0-9]+)", "$1"));
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),this, year,month,day);
    }

}
```

and how is my case in the previous question different to this one

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

(search for "intent.setClass(getActivity(), DetailsActivity.class);" to find the example I'm referring to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example you are extending DialogFragment,  this does not extend from **Activity** but **Fragment**.

Here you are calling the getActivity() method of Fragment which returns the attached Activity object for the Fragment.

In the previous question the class was extending Activity, so '**this**' is a reference to an Activity.

The complication arises because in the previous question you were accessing '**this**' from an anonymous inner class, which dosen't extend from Activity so to access the enclosing object you have to specify the name of the enclosing class i.e **MainActivity.this**.

Here's the Oracle tutorial on inner classes, the syntax can be confusing at first.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html

Comment: hm... so if I understand correctly I can't use `getActivity` to reference an activity I'm in but I should rather use `this` or if the class is anonymous and inner `ActivityToReference.this` ?

Comment: There is no getActivity() method in the class Activity as it wouldn't add anything that `this` already does.
However as Fragment does not inherit from Activity it does have a `getActivity()` method.